# script stuck in try-except block

Tags: python, try-except, twython, spotipy

I am currently working on a Python script that essentially scrapes a given Twitter account for Spotify tracks and creates a playlist of the tracks found. The script is functioning properly for the most part but I am trying to incorporate some error handling and am running into some issues. The first error I want to tackle is when a user enters a Spotify/Twitter username that isn't valid.

So far, I have created 2 separate try-except loops to continuously prompt the user for their Twitter and Spotify usernames until valid ones are entered. The Twitter try-except loop seems to be functioning properly but the Spotify loop gets stuck if an incorrect username is entered (i.e. does not except valid username and won't terminate when ^C is entered).

Twitter try-except loop:

```py
# Get request token from Twitter
    reqclient = Twython(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    reqcreds = reqclient.get_authentication_tokens()

    # Prompt user for Twitter account information until valid account is found
    validated = False
    while validated == False:
        try:
            t_username = input("Please enter your TWITTER username: ")
            user_info = reqclient.show_user(screen_name=t_username)
        # except TwythonError as e:
        except:
            print("Could not find Twitter account " + t_username + ". Please try again.")
            # print(e)
            continue
        else:
            t_user_id = user_info["id"]
            validated = True
```

Spotify try-except loop:

```py
    # Create a SpotifyOAuth object to begin authroization code flow
    scope = 'playlist-modify-public playlist-read-collaborative playlist-read-private playlist-modify-private' # Specifies access/user authorization needed to perform request (i.e. create playlist)
    sp_oauth = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret,redirect_uri=redirect_uri,scope=scope)

    # Prompt user for Spotify account information until valid account is found
    validated = False
    while validated == False:
        try:
            s_username = input("Please enter your SPOTIFY username: ")
            user_info = sp_oauth.current_user()
        except:
            print("Could not find Spotify account " + s_username + ". Please try again.")
            continue
        else:
            s_user_id = user_info["id"]
            validated = True
```

Am I missing something here? I feel like it's really obvious but I can't seem to find the issue (and apologies if this is the case)?

Comment: It is a little unclear if it gets stuck in case of valid or INvalid username? Try to add more logging at different stages (at the end of try statement after input and during the else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going on here.

First, the value of `s_username` that you enter is never actually applied to any sort of Spotify API object, so the result of `sp_oauth.current_user()` is never going to change.

The second, and more important, issue is that you are using a blanket `except` statement which catches *all* exceptions. This is causing problems for you because it's also catching the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception that normally allows you to exit a program by pressing `CTRL-C`. You should *almost always* narrow the exception you are catching to the specific error type you want to handle.

Comment: Thanks so much! Not specifying the type of exception I was looking for was the issue. The Spotify API user authorization process is more involved and I need to rethink my approach of handling the "user not found" error.